# UIButton not highlighting or running code when clicked

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm setting up 26 buttons, adding them as subviews to a letterButtonLabel, and appending them to an letterButtons array.

```
for row in 0..<6 {
            for column in 0..<5 {
                if row == 5 && column > 0 { continue }

                let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
                letterButton.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
                letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

                let frame = CGRect(x: width * column, y: height * row, width: width, height: height)
                letterButton.frame = frame

                letterButtonLabel.addSubview(letterButton)

                letterButtons.append(letterButton)
            }
        }
```

Afterwards, I assign a letter to each button using the letterButtons array.

```
var index = 0

        for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" {
             letterButtons[index].setTitle("\(letter)", for: .normal)
             index += 1
        }
```

I then manually add layout constraints.

Here is the functionality for each button:

```
@objc func letterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // check the letter and react
        sender.isHidden = true

        guard let word = currentWord else { return }
        guard var charactersArray = currentWordField.text?.components(separatedBy: "") else { return }
        guard let originalCurrentWordField = currentWordField.text else { return }

        for (index, letter) in word.enumerated() {
            let strLetter = String(letter)

            if strLetter == sender.titleLabel?.text {
                 charactersArray[index] = strLetter
            }
        }

        currentWordField.text = charactersArray.joined()

        if currentWordField.text == originalCurrentWordField {
            livesLeft -= 1
        }

        if wordBank.contains(word) {
            // you got it! reset letters
            level += 1

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Good job!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: resetForNextLevel)
            ac.addAction(action)

            present(ac, animated: true)
        }


        if livesLeft == 0 {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: resetForNextLevel)

            ac.addAction(action)
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

(adding all just in case)

My button doesn't highlight or click. Is there anything here that might explain the problem? I'm curious about common mistakes.

Comment: Does it work if you use a plain `UIView` as a parent instead of a label?  (Trying to eliminate possibilities.)

Comment: @PhillipMills ah, yes! I didn't realize that I couldn't add it to a label, but that makes perfect common sense. I change the label to a UIView and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel has by default `userInteractionEnabled = false`. 
Setting this to `true` should fix your problem

Comment: Would adding these to a UIView instead of a UILabel be a better practice? I don't actually need the label's functionality and didn't realize that I should use a better way.

Comment: Yes, if you don’t need the labels functionality, a simple UIView would be cleaner.